# is there a way to use qualify in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

the below query works in teradata, is there a way to write the same query in postgresql? I am getting error while running this ppostgresql 10

```
select *
from
    product
qualify
    row_number() over (partition by product_key order by product_no) = 1;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need subquery :

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_key order by product_no) as seq
      from product p
     ) p 
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 14):

Postgres has `distinct on`, which should be even more performant:

```
select distinct on (product_key) p.*
from product p
order by product_key, product_no;
```

This is usually the best method in Postgres to get one row per group.